# Trouble with place_forget()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been trying to get .place_forget() to work in my test application but I am having some difficulty.

I am trying to get the widgets in "def select_1:"  to show when R1 "Yes" checkbox is checked and then have the widgets not show when the check is removed.
The widgets show when I check the box but will not forget(hide) when it is then unchecked.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import os, sys
import pywintypes
from tkinter import *

#================================= MAIN WINDOW =================================
root = Tk()
w = 750
h = 325
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
root.title('Test Application')
root.geometry('750x325')
root.config(bg='#000000')

pass_entry=StringVar()
pass_1=StringVar()
var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
selection = StringVar()

#=================================== HEADER ====================================
header = Label(root, font = ('Times New Roman','25','bold'), text='Test Application',
                bg = ('#000000'), fg = ('#B3CDE0'))
header.place(x=250,y=15)

#================================ RESULT WINDOW ================================
result_window = Text(root, width = 80, height = 10)
result_window.place(x=50, y=75)

#=========================== CHECK BUTTON SELECTION ============================
def select_1():
    if var1.get()==1:
        pass_entry = Entry(root, width = 20, textvariable = pass_1, bg='#000000', fg='#B3CDE0')
        pass_entry.place(x=250,y=275)
        pass_entry.focus_set()

        selection = Label(root, text='Enter OS Password:', bg='#000000', fg='#B3CDE0')
        selection.place(x=140,y=275)

    elif var1.get()==0:
        pass_entry.place_forget()
        selection.place_forget()
    else:
        return

#========================= ACCESS CREDENTIAL MANAGER ===========================
def getpass():
    if var1.get()==1:
        os.system('explorer.exe')
    else:
        return

def close():
    root.destroy()

#=============================== RADIO BUTTONS =================================
R1 = Checkbutton(root, text="Yes", variable = var1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, width = 15,           activebackground = '#000000', bg='#000000', fg='#B3CDE0', command=select_1)
R1.place(x=350,y=250)

 R2 = Checkbutton(root, text="No ", variable = var2, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, width =      15, bg='#000000', fg='#B3CDE0', activebackground = '#000000')
 R2.place(x=350,y=275)

#=========================== RADIO BUTTON SELECTION ============================
cancel_button = Button(root, text='Cancel', width = 12, bg=('#000000'), fg = ('#B3CDE0'),     activebackground = '#000000', command = close)
cancel_button.place(x=590,y=270)

recover_button = Button(root, text='Open', width = 12, bg=('#000000'), fg = ('#B3CDE0'), activebackground = '#000000',command = getpass)
recover_button.place(x=480,y=270)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to reduce this down to a [mcve]. There appears to be a lot of code that is unnecessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `pass_entry` and `selection` are *local variables* within `select_1()`.  The next time the function is called, you get brand new variables, with no memory of the values they had during the previous call.

Comment: jasonharper, thank you, can you suggest a that might help me to get the result I am trying for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to make a widget disappear and then appear again, you don't actually have to define it and all it's options again.

```
#=========================== CHECK BUTTON SELECTION ============================
    pass_entry = Entry(root, width = 20, textvariable = pass_1, bg='#000000', fg='#B3CDE0')
    selection = Label(root, text='Enter OS Password:', bg='#000000', fg='#B3CDE0')

    def select_1():
        if var1.get()==1:
            pass_entry.place(x=250,y=275)
            pass_entry.focus_set()

            selection.place(x=140,y=275)

        elif var1.get()==0:
            pass_entry.place_forget()
            selection.place_forget()
        else:
            return
```

Notice how `pass_entry` and `selection` are defined ***outside*** of the function and only placed inside the function.

What's a bit confusing though is why you're using two separate buttons for "yes" and "no" if checking them doesn't automatically uncheck the other one (i assume that's the purpose of the two buttons).

If that's what you want to do, you should use the `Radiobutton` widget instead. Notice how both of them affect the same variable and each of them have one value.

```
#=============================== RADIO BUTTONS =================================
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Yes", variable = var1, value = 1, height=1, width = 15, activebackground = '#000000', bg='#000000', fg='#B3CDE0', command=select_1)
R1.place(x=350,y=250)

R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="No", variable = var1, value = 0, height=1, width = 15, activebackground = '#000000', bg='#000000', fg='#B3CDE0', command=select_1)
R2.place(x=350,y=275)
```

I also tidied up the other options a bit too, you had some random spacing in there.

Comment: kippel, this makes much more sense now.  I had been reading about the forget method for a couple hours checking and rechecking the method however none of the prior posts or internet searches explained how or why it works but rather gave various examples.
Excellent explanation and clarity, I greatly appreciate that.